# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I have a used SignalR for creating a chat. It works perfectly but when I use it
in master pages it gives the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined
(anonymous function)
fire
self.fireWith
jQuery.extend.ready
DOMContentLoaded
```

The error lies at:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      var chat = $.connection.chat;
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chat' of undefined**

      $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'auto' }, function () {
        //alert('connected');
        $('#MainContent_connected').text('Connected to chat room');
      });

      $("#broadcast").click(function () {
        chat.send($("#MainContent_userName").text() + $("#msg").val());
        $("#msg").val('')
      });

      /* Declaring the Function on the chat hub in order for the server to
      be able to invoke it. */
      chat.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
      };
    });
  </script>
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have jQuery included twice?

Comment: At first I didn't. I had it only on Master Page and I was getting 3 other errors but after I included the src on the pages within the folder, this is the only error

Comment: That error is 100% of the time when jQuery is included twice. It's saying that $.connection itself is undefined. This means the jQuery plugin for SignalR isn't even loading properly. 

If you're getting that error then you have jQuery included twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're including the script tag: `<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>`

This dynamic proxy ("signalr/hubs") is what creates the .chat property off of $.connection

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have used both :'<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'and src="signalr/hubs">  but still nothing. It seems to work on the public pages of the web application but not on the "Admin" one

Comment: Is the admin page on a different domain?

Comment: They just have different access rules and they lie on a different folder (which I believe this is the issue) but at the end I just created a chat.aspx, added an iframe on the master page referencing the chat and somehow found a solution on that matter